# form indicates that it was sent, but I receive nothing

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an issue with my form that I can't seem to solve and I hope someone here can help. Please see code down below.

This is the check and send code, there is something I'm missing

```
<script type="text/javascript">

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
    function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

        $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
        $this->email = trim($details['email']);
        $this->subject = 'Massage'; // Subject 
        $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

        $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
        $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '';
    }


    private function validateEmail(){
        $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

        if($this->email == '') { 
            return false;
        } else {
            $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
        }

        return empty($string) ? true : false;
    }


    private function validateFields(){
        // Check name
        if(!$this->name)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>name please</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check email
        if(!$this->email)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>email please</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check valid email
        if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>email not right</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check message length
        if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>To short please more then '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }
    }


    private function sendEmail(){
        $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
             "Van: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
            ."Reageer op: ".$this->email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . HTMLversion());

        if($mail)
        {
            $this->response_status = 1;
            $this->response_html = '<p>E-mail send</p>';
        }
    }


    function sendRequest(){
        $this->validateFields();
        if($this->response_status)
        {
            $this->sendEmail();
        }

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
        $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, 
$message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

 </script>
```

This is the script I use to check and send the email.

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="/contact.html" target="_self" method="post"
    <p class="contact-name">
        <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p class="contact-email">
        <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
    </p>
    <p class="contact-message">
        <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="contact-submit">
        <a style="color: white;" id="contact-submit" class="submit" value="submit">Send Your Email</a>
    </p>

    <div id="response">

    </div>
</form>
```

everything seems to be working, but the email is not being received or maybe not even send.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `Van` and `Reageer op` are not recognized email headers. Perhaps you meant `From` and `Reply-To`? Most email services (like GMail) will probably reject incoming emails with weird headers like these. Setting up DKIM and SPF records for your domain would also be a good idea.

Comment: When you execute your code, in what way does it seem that is working? Is the `$mail` true? If so check your spam folder and check your mail server logs.

Comment: let me check and get back to you..

Comment: didn't work thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have your php-code inside `<script>` tags, but you should be using `<?php [your script] ?>` instead.

Also, the opening-tag of your form is missing a `>`.

Comment: I can't use a .PHP I can only use .HTML  and thanks for the correction.

Comment: @D.Man as far as I know, there is no way to use PHP in a file without the .php extension. What's the reason you can't use a .php file?

Comment: It changes the hole file to just text when I open it

Comment: @D.Man It sounds like you try to run the file from your pc, not from a server. You need to install xampp first, and run the .php file through there. There a lot of tutorials for this online.

Comment: this is going to be a long long process, I will just add the info and google maps. thanks for help and sorry for wasting everyones time!

Comment: No problem! Though, if you are planning on continuing with web development, I would suggest getting php up and running. It takes some time to set up, but I think it´s worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The action on your form is an HTML file, which will do nothing.

You need the form processing script to be a php file (I'm assuming your server is already capable of handling php) and the action on the form should be something like

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="/contact.php" target="_self" method="post">
```

please note that I also added the closing ">" sign after post, as the <form> tag was still open.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using PHP inside a HTML script tag with a type attribute set to "text/javascript"

Try with

```
<script language=php>
    ...Your code here...
</script>
```

Or with the basic php tags

Comment: So I'm frosted to change the hole file from .html to .php. now I need to find out why the file is not working properly...